# AngularJs: Unable to uncheck checkbox when uncheck another checkbox

Tags: angularjs, checkbox, ionic-framework

Got a problem, here the situation:
I want to uncheck the first checkbox when I uncheck the second checkbox.
Let say, by default both checkbox are checked. When I click second checkbox, I want the first checkbox to uncheck also.

HTML:

```
<ion-checkbox ng-model="firstCheckbox">First Checkbox</ion-checkbox>
<ion-checkbox ng-model="secondCheckbox" ng-change="uncheckFirstCheckbox(secondCheckbox)">Second Checkbox</ion-checkbox>
```

JS:

```
    $scope.uncheckFirstCheckbox = function(secondCheckbox) {
        if(secondCheckbox.checked === false) {
            $scope.firstCheckbox = false;
        };
    };
```

The `$scope.firstCheckbox` turn false but it remain uncheck in HTML. 
May I know where could be the problem?

Comment: try `if(!$scope.secondCheckbox) { $scope.firstCheckbox = false; };`, dont pass the value which are there on $scope in function calls as a good practise

Comment: Thank you for your tips :) @entre

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to access `secondCheckbox.checked` property but `secondCheckbox` is already `false`. You should be only checking `secondCheckbox` for a `false` value. Use `if(!secondCheckbox)` instead for the condition.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/divyanshu013/t7g6ryf2/1/) is a working fiddle of your code.

**HTML**

```
<ion-checkbox ng-model="firstCheckbox">First Checkbox</ion-checkbox>
<ion-checkbox ng-model="secondCheckbox" ng-change="uncheckFirstCheckbox(secondCheckbox)">Second Checkbox</ion-checkbox>
```

**JS**

```
$scope.uncheckFirstCheckbox = function(secondCheckbox) {
    if (!secondCheckbox) {
        $scope.firstCheckbox = false;
    };
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! @Divyanshu